# How to parse a CSV file using Windows Service?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, csv

How to parse a CSV file using Windows Service?

References to any articles or tutorials would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a CSV parser in your windows service.

There is a built in one in the BCL - the [TextFiledParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) and many people like using the third party [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/) library.

Answer (score 1):

This Linq to CSV codeproject.com code has worked well for me. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQtoCSV.aspx